# How to setup Unicorn validator plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have cloned the Unicorn-Plugin Repository from GitHub in my server, But when I open Gerrit code review Its showing that "Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository."

I need to test this plugin for my builds which are already configured.

Answer (score 0):

Form the documentation of Unicorn validator:

Steps to create a new job:

- Check out the unicorn-template project from Git:
- git@github.com:nej/unicorn-template.git
- Reload Jenkins' configuration
- Click on "New Job".
- Enter a "Job name".
- Select "Copy existing job" and enter "unicorn-template" into the "Copy - from" field.
- Click "OK".
- Disable the "Disable Build" option.
- Setup your build trigger
- Fill in your "Site to validate" url
- Click "Save".

source: [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Unicorn+Validation+Plugin)

Comment: Yeah I have followed these but when am giving unicorn-template in the copy from, it says no such build job is present

Comment: I’m guessing that there was a problem reloading the config can you confirm that it was reloaded correctly